# Android, iOS, Windows Phone App On Single C# code

Tags: c#, android, ios, mono, windows-phone

i have an app writen on **c#** for **windows phone marketplace** and i want to use this app and place it into **android marketplace**. Do you know if is that possible with **mono**?

Do you know if i had to **rewrite** some part of code in order to port a windows phone app to android or is possible without this proccess?

As **developer i am thinking the difficulties** to understand how is possible when windows phone devices have different Tasks from Android and maybe different hardware. For example My NumberTaskChoose on Windows Phone may have different events from the same Task on Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to rewrite most of the code, but if you are fluent in C#, you could reuse part of it by using Xamarin (http://xamarin.com). But keep in mind that you will have to create again the UI for every platform, Xamarin will only allow you to reuse the core of your app.

I think there is nothing else you can do.